# Getting desktop icon size with LVM_GETITEMRECT message

Tags: c#, syslistview32

I've been fighting with this all night.  I just don't what is wrong.  I'm trying to get the desktop icon + caption size.  I have some functions that find the desktop handle and put it in a variable called SysListView32_hwnd.  I have verified it is correct with a windows spy program.  Here is the part I am having trouble with.

```
Rectangle rct = new Rectangle();
IntPtr pRct = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(rct));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(rct, pRct, true);

SendMessage(SysListView32_hwnd, LVM_GETITEMRECT, (IntPtr)0, pRct);

Rectangle Rect = (Rectangle)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pRct, typeof(Rectangle));
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pRct);
Debug.WriteLine(Rect.Height + "    " + Rect.Width);
```

It crashes explorer every time.
C# Visual Studio 2010
Windows 7 x64 and I am compiling as a 64 bit program

[Here](http://users.zoominternet.net/~charleswatson/Icon.zip) is my full app if needed

Comment: Do you know which line is crashing explorer / causing the exception?

Comment: @jardarnel27 That's easy, it's the SendMessage

Comment: @David Easy for you, maybe.  It's just good practice to say, in the question, where the program is blowing up.  That way people don't have to assume / guess.

Comment: @jadarnel you make a good point and I do agree, I just happen to know exactly what's going on here

Comment: What is this? I answered the question already. You should not add more and more questions. You should accept the answer and upvote if it was helpful - clearly it was. If you have a different question, ask a new question. Please take a read of the [faq].

Comment: The faq says
What if I don’t get a good answer?

First, make sure you’ve asked a good question. To get better answers, you may need to put additional effort into your question. Edit your question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer your question. This will naturally bump your question and get more people interested in it.  Not that your answer wasn't good David, but I don't completely understand yet.

Comment: Your second question is a good question too. I have answered it with a second answer. I feel quite strongly that this should have been two questions. All the same, they are both answered now!!

Comment: The section of the faq you quoted is for when you don't get an answer to the question. What it is getting at is that you may need to clarify the original question. What happened here is that you went on to do follow-up work to which you had a couple of queries. Those queries were a new question. Anyway, I realise you are new here and I'm just trying to help. Next time I think you should ask the follow up as a new question. Enough said now, I've probably made too much of this.

Answer (score 2):

*This addresses the additional questions asked in the extensive edit to the question.*

> It seems to me like we are working with `LVITEMs` but `VirtualAllocEx` specifies `sizeof(uint)`.

The documentation of the `dwSize` parameter of [`VirtualAllocEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366890%28VS.85%29.aspx), on MSDN, states:

> The size of the region of memory to allocate, in bytes.
>
> If lpAddress is NULL, the function rounds dwSize up to the next page boundary.
>
> If lpAddress is not NULL, the function allocates all pages that contain one or more bytes in the range from lpAddress to lpAddress+dwSize. This means, for example, that a 2-byte range that straddles a page boundary causes the function to allocate both pages.

In other words it allocates entire pages. Since a page is 4KB you are getting luck. You should ensure that `dwSize` is big enough for the buffer you need.

> Why does pszText = (IntPtr)((int)lpBaseAddress + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LVITEM)))? Wouldn't that just point to the end of the structure.

Yes it does point to the end of the structure. The point is that the `pszText` field of `LVITEM` must point to a buffer allocated by the caller. Whoever wrote this code chose to use the spare buffer space at the end of the struct. Since the struct declares that `pszText` contains 256 bytes, that will easily fit into the remains of the 4KB page. So it works, but it is a little opaque.

Answer (score 1):

*This addresses the original question before the extensive edit.*

It fails because, the way you have written it can only work when you call from the process that owns the target window handle. This is because you pass a pointer, but that is only valid in your process. As soon as it lands in the other process it refers to an address that is meaningless. And even if it did mean something, a process can't read another processes memory with help from the system. Naturally explorer bombs.

The solution is to use `VirtualAllocEx()` to allocate memory in the explorer process. Then send the message. Then use `ReadProcessMemory()` to marshal the contents of the rect back into your process. The most commonly cited code sample for this is this [Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/int64_memsteal.aspx). That example is using `LVM_GETITEMTEXT` but the principles are identical.